# Secured applications

Tags: c#, c++, security

How can Write and Create Safer Windows Applications with lock key ?

Comment: Don't distribute them at all.  If that's not secure enough, the only more secure option is to never write the application.

Comment: by deleting the whole code and destroying the harddisk.
no appliction is 100% safe....

Comment: This question is meaningless in its current form. You need to define more precisely what "100% secure" means to you. Secure against what kinds of attacks, in what environment, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one application that is 100% secure - one that no one uses.

I don't believe 100% security is possible.

If you can define what you really want, maybe you'll have a better chance at getting a useful answer.